# How to remove extra kernels from Ubuntu22.04?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, grub-efi, grub-legacy

I have so many GRUB entries, how can I get rid of all but one?
[image]

I want to use only one bootloader entry.

Also, there is a bootloader of a Windows installation when it is actually installed on another disk. How to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all the other entries and remove all the other kernels, but it is inadvisable.

You can, however run the commands:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

To automatically remove the unnecessary kernels. Otherwise, to remove other kernels, for earch kernel, issue the command:

```
sudo apt purge linux-image-$KVER
```

where, in your case it will mean: 6.0.3.76060003-generic (and so on). Also understand that linux and initrd are actually a single entry, not two.

For remove the Windows entry, set the variable

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
```

in /etc/default/grub.

Needless to say, this is extremely inadvisable, as you will not be able to boot to windows without the help of BIOS boot selection.

Comment: I already boot to Windows with the help of BIOS boot selection